# An application of Serre Duality

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles

This is problem 2 of Chapter 5 in Voisin's book *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry I*.

Let $X$ be a connected compact complex manifold of dimension $n$ and let $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle on $X$. We assume that there exists an integer $N>0$, such that $$H^0(X,L^{\otimes N})\neq 0.$$Show that if $H^n(X,L\otimes K_X)\neq0$, the line bundle $L$ is trivial.

The question is named after An application of Serre duality but I did not figure out how.

Comment: $H^n(L\otimes K_X)\neq 0$ implies by Serre duality, $H^0(L^{-1})\neq 0$.

Comment: @Mohan Yes. I can get that step. But why this and $H^0(X,l^{\otimes N})\neq 0$ can imply the bundle is trivial? Is it because we can find a nowhere vanishing section of $L$ by these two conditions?

Comment: This implies $H^0(L^{-N})\neq 0$ and coupled with $H^0(L^N)\neq 0$, you get $L^N$ is trivial and thus $L^{-N}$. But $L^{-1}$ is effective and $L^{-N}$ is trivial implies $L^{-1}$ and thus $L$ is trivial.